# Unable to download anything after hibernation with Kaspersky

Tags: browser, download, hibernate, kaspersky

On a Windows 7 computer, I regularly use IE9 F12 tools to monitor network traffic. These tools can be opened in one or more IE9 windows, when I'm experiencing the issue.

### What is this issue?

After long time F12 tools *was* -or- *are* monitoring traffic, I can't download anything from any application, except HTTP webpages. I'm unable to receive FLV video data from websites like youtube.com, or download a file from websites like microsoft.com -- neither from *Internet Explorer*, *Firefox* nor *Orbit Downloader*.

### Symptoms

- On like YouTube.com, I see the thumbnail, but not the video (permanently loading)
- On every websites, I can click on links to download file, but the browser is permanently waiting for the server response
- On Orbit Downloader, HTTP headers are submitted to the server, and HTTP response headers are received, but no data is coming

I just can see webpages, and graphics on webpages (i.e. jpg, png) may not be downloaded as well.

### What about the hardware?

Problem appears in the same way, with my LAN or my WLAN NIC. So I think this is not a NIC-related issue.

### Temporary workaround

I have to reboot my computer to download files.

Did somebody already encounter this problem?

Comment: The problem may be caused by Kaspersky Anti-Virus, as reported here: http://windows7forums.com/windows-vista-networking/31118-i-have-problem-donwloading-internet-after-hibernate.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this problem is due to the following things:

- Kaspersky Anti-Virus is unstable after hibernation, if before hibernation the update was not finished
- This make browsers unable to download anything, because Internet Anti-Virus Kaspersky module is blocked (neither enabled nor disabled)

To fix the problem, you can:

- Shutdown and close Kaspersky
- Close your browser, in order to Kaspersky can close itself because there isn't HTTP connections anymore
- Launch your browser and delete all cache

After that, your downloads will work again.